# Meteor : How to contain draggable object

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am new to meteor , but from want I understand its draggable object has jquery under the hood. I added the draggable object by using

```
li id="data-item-sortable-id"
```

I would like to be able to contain the area the draggable object can move in. 
In jquery you would do something like

```
var containmentTop = $("#stop-top").position().top;
var containmentBottom = $("#stop-bottom").position().top;

$('#bar').draggable({axis: 'y', containment : [0,containmentTop,0,containmentBottom] });
```

Does anyone have a good example of how to make meteor contain where its draggable object can go?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery UI, Containment is usually based on an Element, Selector, or a specific string value.

> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region.
>
> **Element:** An element to use as the container.
>
> **Selector:** A selector specifying an element to use as the container.
>
> **String:** A string identifying an element to use as the container. Possible values: `"parent"`, `"document"`, `"window"`
>
> **Array:** An array defining a bounding box in the form `[ x1, y1, x2, y2 ]`

I have not used Meteor, but I suspect that you can get the containment you want by the following:

```
var cTop = $("#stop-top").position();
var cBottom = $("#stop-bottom").position();

$('#bar').draggable({
  axis: 'y',
  containment: [ cTop.left, cTop.top, cBottom.left, cBottom.top ]
});
```

Personally, I would just use something like `"parent"`.

If this doesn't work, may need to see a more complete example.

Remember that `left` is the X-Axis and `top` is the Y-Axis.